# Noobie dealing with sculpting artifacts

Tags: sculpting, error, artifacts

Not sure exactly how to explain the problem, but when using particularly deflate, smooth, or slide relax, even with dyntopo on I get shiny artifacts, usually lumps with deflate, and longer strips with attempting to smooth a surface that was fine. Wondering what is causing this and how to avoid or quickly clean it up. [image]

Comment: What blender version are you using?

Comment: Currently on 3.0

Comment: Can you supply your .blend file?